# Using Foundation Icons with AddThis Social Plugins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, icons, zurb-foundation, addthis

I was wondering if anyone has been able to use Foundation Icons from http://foundation.zurb.com/icon-fonts.php, http://www.zurb.com/playground/foundation-icons with AddThis social plugins - http://www.addthis.com/social-plugins#.UVDkahyk85o -  or would know how to do this.

There is definitely a way to use custom images rather than the default AddThis icons.  However, the only way I've seen this done is like this:

`<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style">
     <a class="addthis_button_facebook_send"><img src="..."></a> 
</div>`

All you do is put your custom image inside the `<a>` tag.  But with Foundation Icons, they are implemented with the `<i>` tag.

I would really like to use the Facebook Send button, but with my facebook Foundation Icon.  Can anyone help?

Comment: I think the AddThis buttons only work with images.  The fact that Foundation Icons are implemented with fonts and sprites and whatnot is the cause for this not working.  Quite the bummer.